# Searching a String using C#

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have the following String `"</script><div id='PO_1WTXxKUTU98xDU1'><!--DO NOT REMOVE-CONTENTS PLACED HERE--></div>"`

I require to get the attribute value from the div tag. How can i retrieve this using C#.

Comment: So... What did you try?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56107/what-is-the-best-way-to-parse-html-in-c ...and in-particular: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6244203/608764

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're a masochist you can do this old school VB3 style:

```
        string input = @"</script><div id='PO_1WTXxKUTU98xDU1'><!--DO NOT REMOVE-CONTENTS PLACED HERE--></div>";
        string startString = "div id='";

        int startIndex = input.IndexOf(startString);

        if (startIndex != -1)
        {
            startIndex += startString.Length;
            int endIndex = input.IndexOf("'", startIndex);
            string subString = input.Substring(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Avoid** parsing html with `regex`

`Regex` is not a good choice for parsing `HTML` files..

HTML is not strict nor is it regular with its format..

Use [htmlagilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

You can do it like this with htmlagilityPack.

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load(yourStream);
List<string> itemList = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@id]")//selects all div having id attribute
.Select(x=>x.Attributes["id"].Value)//select the id attribute value
.ToList<string>();
//itemList will now contain all div's id attribute value
```

Comment: Who said anything about regex?

Comment: @JonB he has tagged it with regex

Comment: So you think you're smart just because you know how to read? Pfft!

Comment: @JonB u think tht u r smart..y not post ur own ans then..pffman

Comment: You don't need to shout "You cannot parse HTML with regex" Read this first http://stackoverflow.com/a/4234491/932418

Comment: @L.B agreed but `regex` is not made for parsing html.it is used for regularly occurring things which is not in the case of html..

Answer (score 0):

Strictly solving the question asked, one of a myriad ways of solving it would be to isolate the `div` element, parse it as an `XElement` and then pull the attribute's value that way.

```
        string bobo = "</script><div id='PO_1WTXxKUTU98xDU1'><!--DO NOT REMOVE-CONTENTS PLACED HERE--></div>";
        string justDiv = bobo.Substring(bobo.IndexOf("<div"));
        XElement xelem = XElement.Parse(justDiv);
        var id = xelem.Attribute("id");
        var value = id.Value;
```

There are certainly lots of ways to solve this but this one answers the mail.

Comment: i dnt think using linq2xml is a good way to solve this problem..specially if its html

Comment: Well, you're certainly allowed your opinion.  It *does* answer the question though and doesn't take a dependency on another library to do it.

Answer (score -1):

A .NET Regex that looks something like this will do the trick

```
^</script><div id='(?<attrValue>[^']+)'.*$
```

you can then get hold of the value as

```
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, @"^</script><div id='(?<attrValue>[^']+)'.*$");
if (matches.Count > 0)
{
    var attrValue = matches[0].Groups["attrValue"];
}
```